# DataTables error logging out user on 302 response

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-4, datatables

I've got two problems with a Laravel based site that I'm attempting to upgrade.
It's using DataTables for a lot of reports that I really don't want to have to rewrite but from time to time I'm getting 302 (found) responses instead of JSON.
This leads to problem two: when this happens, the user gets logged out.

Does anyone have any suggestions what could cause these issues?

Using:
Laravel 4.1.27
jQuery 1.8.3
PHP 5.5.19
DataTables 1.10.0

One of the DataTables calls:

```
function makeMiscItemsTable(tableSelector, url) {
    if (url === undefined) {
        miscItemsTable = $(tableSelector).DataTable({
            "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex) {
                $(nRow).children('.donation-id').html(['<a title="View/Edit" href="/inventory/donation/details/', aData['donation_id'], '">',     aData['donation_id'], '</a>'].join(""));
                // Apply stying to rows based on the item's status: received, recycled or sent/other
                if (aData['status'] == 'sent') {
                    $(nRow).addClass('row-blue');
                } else if (aData['status'] == 'recycled') {
                    $(nRow).addClass('row-red');
                } else {
                    $(nRow).addClass('row-green');
                }
            },
            "oLanguage": {
                "sProcessing": "<img src='/assets/images/ajax_clock_small.gif'>",
                "sSearch": ""
            },
            "bDeferRender": true,
            "bProcessing": true,
            "sAjaxSource": '/inventory/donation/misc_items',
            "sPaginationType": "four_button",
            "bRetrieve": true,
            "aaSorting": [[1, "desc"]],
            'aLengthMenu': [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, 'All']],
            'iDisplayLength': 25,
            'aoColumns': [
                {
                    "mDataProp": null,
                    "sClass": "center-text",
                    "sDefaultContent": '<input type="checkbox" name="misc-item-select" class="misc-item-check" value="selected" false>'
                },
                {
                    "mDataProp": 'donation_id',
                    "sClass": 'donation-id'
                },
                {"mDataProp": 'description'},
                {
                    "mDataProp": 'status',
                    "sClass": "hide"
                },
                {
                    "mDataProp": 'id',
                    "sClass": "hide misc-item-id"
                }
            ],
            "aoColumnDefs": [
                {'bSortable': false,
                    'aTargets': [0]
                }
            ]
        });
    } else {
        miscItemsTable.ajax.url(url).load();
    }
}
```

The controller code:

```
public function get_misc_items($status = null)
    {
        $attributes = DonatedMiscItem::$datatable_attributes;

        if ($status === null) {
            $items = DonatedMiscItem::all($attributes);
        } else {
            $items = DonatedMiscItem::where('status', $status)->get($attributes);
        }

        $results = array();
        $count = $items->count();

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $results[] = $item['original'];
        }

        return Response::json(array('aaData' => $results, 'iTotalRecords' => $count, 'iTotalDisplayRecords' => $count));
    }
```

The route:

```
 Route::get('donation/misc_items/{status?}', 'DonationController@get_misc_items');
```

The URL called:

```
site.com/inventory/donation/misc_items?_=1425080932188
```

Comment: If the cache busting timestamp at end of url is being created at runtime for each ajax call the browser shouldn't be able to cache the request

Answer (score 0):

The 302 respose is a redirect, and is probably triggered from an application session timeout, that's why the users gets logged out at the same time. Check the location header to find if the actual url of the redirect is a login page.